# Friendly URL with complex query

Tags: routes, friendly-url

I searched for the keyword "CTO" in google and got this URL in the address bar. 
And I am wondering can anybody make this into a friendly URL.

http://www.google.com.ng/search?hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=cto&oq=cto&gs_l=serp.3...939821.940377.0.940735.3.3.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0.UflIOzQsuv4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1066&bih=646&ech=1&psi=0CX0T7iHBoXU-gbn96TvBg.1341400545114.3&emsg=NCSR&noj=1&ei=0CX0T7iHBoXU-gbn96TvBg

My question is that is it possible to have a friendly url that is equivalent to this? If true, how?

```
Example: http://www.google.com.ng/search/{mysearchcriteria}
```

Comment: First, lets define what *friendly url* means.

Answer (score 0):

Use a service like [bitly.com](http://bitly.com) or [TinyURL](http://tinyurl.com).  The idea is simple, take a URL, store it in a datastore (most likely NoSQL), and assign it a unique identifier, and issue an HTTP redirect whenever you receive the identifier.  The real trick is in managing the datastore that maps the URLs.  Give [this blog post](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/bitly_alternative_to_tinyurl.php) a read to understand bit.ly a little more.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.google.com/search?q=CTO

this will give you same result